# @font-face not working in polymer/web-components

Tags: web, components, font-face, polymer

I'm trying to get a web font into my polymer component, however the font is failing to render. Could someone shed some light on this? Google hasn't been giving me much love on this issue. If you need any more info then just let me know. Thanks!

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'open_sansextrabold';
src: url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold-webfont.svg#open_sansextrabold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

header a {
font-family: "open_sansextrabold";
display: block;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
transition: background-color 1s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 140ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
-moz-transition: all 140ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
 -o-transition: all 140ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
    transition: all 140ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); /* ease-in-out */

-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
-moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
 -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); /* ease-in-out */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

OK, so I have worked this out.
The `@font-face` needs to be loaded outside of the `<template>`.
Not sure why, but it's all working now.

Comment: Completing answer - Outside of the <Polymer-Element>. +1

Comment: Moving @font-face ouside of the Polymer element and fix relative url works for me as well! Thanks @Monty!

Comment: The reason for that is that - until today - Chrome does not support @font-face definitions inside shadow dom. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2386 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336876

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct to me but I'm also used to having problem with the font-face...

Just to be sure, is the css containing your font-face at the good level to reach the folder /fonts? For instance if you have a css folder containing this file you should use

```
url('../fonts/...)
```

Did you also check with different browsers ?