# Web components - Fonts and Material icons not working (@font-face)

Tags: fonts, font-face, web-component

I am trying to create a web component using vue cli 3 by running following command

`vue-cli-service build --target wc --name wc-demo 'src/App.vue'`

I am facing issue with loading fonts and material icons inside web components.

I am importing **roboto-font.scss** and **material-icon.scss** inside style tag of **App.vue** which is entry for creating web component.

```
<style lang='scss'>
// @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap');
@import "~@/assets/fonts/roboto-font/roboto-font.scss";
@import "~@/assets/fonts/material-icons/material-icons.scss";
</style>
```

**Material-icon.scss**

```
$font-dir: "assets/fonts/material-icons/web-font/";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  // src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v48/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2') format("woff2");

  src: url("#{$font-dir}flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("#{$font-dir}flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNa.woff") format("woff");
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

**Roboto-font.scss**

```
$font-dir: "assets/fonts/roboto-font/web-font/";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url("#{$font-dir}KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxIIzQ.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Everything works fine when running project using

> yarn serve

. Fonts load fine in network tab, but after building web component and loading it in browser using “**live server**”, the fonts does not load in network tab.

Only way I could make fonts and icons work is by adding link tags to index.html file. But not within web component (within shadow Dom)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>wc-demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src=“./wc-demo.js"></script>
    <wc-demo></wc-demo>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to understand how to include fonts within web component or using it in the html file head section is the only option ?

Also I have linked some similar issues that might help you to help many like me :-

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336876

[@font-face not working in polymer/web-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675534/font-face-not-working-in-polymer-web-components)

https://robdodson.me/at-font-face-doesnt-work-in-shadow-dom/

[Why doesn't Font Awesome work in my Shadow DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546007/why-doesnt-font-awesome-work-in-my-shadow-dom)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this question still relevant for the author, but:

I made quite a research regarding this topic and I found out that:

**There is no way to import fonts from inside of the web component**.
Web components are self isolated. They have their own DOM tree. That's basically means that any styles **included to head** of parent document **will not be available** inside the web-component.

Only ways to use custom fonts inside the web-component are:

**a)** Disable shadow dom. Then you can fetch fonts in parent file (e.g. head tag) and use those fonts from inside the web component.

**b)** Include fonts definitions to both: parent and web-component (which is code duplication).

**UPDATE**

After some experiments it seems I found the solution.
In the following example I am using **StencilJS** which is tool dedicated for web-components development.

Using javascript / typescript it is possible to fetch the styles node of the shadow root element.
To access this element I am using following:

```js
@Element() private element: HTMLElement;
```

From StencilJS docs:

> The @Element() decorator is how to get access to the host element within the class instance. This returns an instance of an HTMLElement, so standard DOM methods/events can be used here.

And now I am able to access styles node and set (import) fronts there. Join the fonts import as a regular string to the style:

```js
this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector('style').innerText += "@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almendra+Display&family=Open+Sans:wght@200&display=swap');";
this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector('style').innerText += "p {font-family: 'Almendra Display', cursive;}";
```

That is the solution I used for the web-component built using Stencil. I strongly believe same can be achieved using React. And I think it can be done without any framework usage too.